SSH does not return exit code of last command
I exexcute
$ ssh remotehost "exit 1"
$ echo $?
0

The result is 0 and not 1.
I have read here on stackoverflow, that it should be 1. What is going wrong? TIA!

Update (Solution):
ssh is a function on that site, and there is one command executed after the ssh call.
Executing /usr/bin/ssh remotehost "exit 1", the exit-code is 1.
Thanks to @jeb :)

Your (modified) environment destroys the exitcode. You should do some checks. which ssh, type ssh, ssh -vvv remotehost "exit 1", echo $PROMPT_COMMAND, false and then echo $?

@jeb Oh. You are right: ssh is a function, and there is one command executed after ...

Some hints to find such problems.

Check if the command is an alias or redirected:
type ssh, which ssh or use \ssh remotehost "exit 1"
Check if your prompt modifies the exitcode:
false followed by echo $? should output a 1
echo $PROMPT_COMMAND shows if there is an user defined prompt function active, unset it
Check the command itself:
ssh -vvv remotehost "exit 1" it should show the exitcode in the last debug line, something like debug1: Exit status 1

